# how to make Mac detect AVR board using USBasp and burn program to it?

Tags: usb, embedded-systems, avr

I am new to Embedded, starting with **AVR programming using C**. I am working on **Mac OS 10.9.4**, so far I am using **avrdude** and **xCode** as IDE. It works very well, for now I am testing my code using **Proteus**.

But now I want to burn my **.hex** to **AVR ATMega16** board. I have **USBasp**, which I am able to connect and it lights up the board. Now after searching on the internet, I think Mac is not detecting my board. I have checked **/dev** directory, but no usb device found.

So I am not sure what to next, how to make Mac detect my board and burn my .hex on it. I've found this: http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/ but no idea how to use this or its required or not.

So question stand is: **how to make Mac detect AVR board using USBasp and burn program to it?**

FYI: I've installed **CrossPack** on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading AVR and CrossPack docs, I've found really easy to do this.

For AVR development environment setup, do the following thing:

1. Install [xCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) on your Mac, choose latest version.
2. Now install [CrossPack](http://www.obdev.at/crosspack/).

This will do all the environment setup. CrossPack installs required libs to support USBasp as well.

To create project using xCode:

1. Create new project
2. Select xAVR project on next screen
3. Next set MCU you are using, Programmer to USBAsp, Frequency as needed.

There you go, try a first first time build it may fail, but try again it will work smooth.

You can use **AVR DUDE** directly from Terminal:

```
avrdude -c usbasp -p <partno> -P usb -v
```